# Angular 4 - NgModel and Radio Buttons 2 Way Binding

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i have a page where a user selects a language. The language list appears in a modal. The modal contains a group of radio checkboxes. The user selects a language and presses done to close the modal. The user can reselect a language in the same process.

If a language has already been selected, you would expect the language to already be set/selected/checked when the modal is loaded but this is not the case.

LanguageList.ts

```
export class LanguageListPage {

    language: any;
    languages: any;

    isReadyToSave: boolean;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public util: UtilProvider, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {

        this.getLanguages();

        if (this.navParams.get("language")) {
            this.language = this.navParams.get("language");
            console.log(this.language); // P.S it does return the correct value here

        }
    }
```

LanguageList.html

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="language" (ngModelChange)="setReadyState()">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let language of languages">
        <ion-label color="dark">{{language.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-note item-end>{{language.native}}</ion-note>
        <ion-radio [value]="language"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

language object example

```
{code: "JA", name: "Japanese", native: "日本語 (にほんご)"}
```

**Can someone help me fix it so that when the user returns to select a language, if they have already picked one previously, there old selection is still checked.**

```
this.navParams.get("language") // This is there old selection
```

if it exists i set it to this.language but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Maybe you could use  <ion-radio [checked]="language.name === selectedLanguage"  [value]="language"></ion-radio>

Comment: this does not work

Comment: Are you comparing language name with selectedLanguage that is also a language name (both should be same type) ? Maybe try to compare language.name with string "Japanese" just to see if [checked] is working -  hoppefuly japanese radio should be checked.